# ¿Cómo puedo hacer limpieza con comandos en python?

Tags: python

Estoy buscando algún comando para poder hacer limpieza de algunas cosas en python (Uso pycharm).
Para poner en contexto, estoy acostumbrado a usar Matlab, y estoy buscando comandos del tipo clear, clc, close all (básicamente comandos que me permitan limpiar las variables que tenga guardadas, limpiar la consola, y cerrar las figuras que tenga abiertas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como tal si lo que buscas es liberar memoria déjame comentarte que Python hace su propia gestión mediante un administrador de su propiedad, tal cual como lo dice en su documentación:

> "*El administrador de memoria de Python garantiza internamente la gestión de este montón privado. El administrador de memoria de Python tiene diferentes componentes que se ocupan de varios aspectos de la gestión dinámica del almacenamiento, como compartir, segmentación, asignación previa o almacenamiento en caché.*"  - Python Software Foundation.

En caso dado que lo que quieras es eliminar variables u objetos que ya no son necesarios o simplemente dale una administración propia, puedes usar la función `del` para borrar variable u objetos manualmente.

Ejemplo del uso de `del`:

```
lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

del lista

#Ahora ya no existe lista
```

Resultado al invocar la lista:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(lista)
NameError: name 'lista' is not defined
```

Si lo que buscas es darle un control más general, puedes hacer uso de la librería **gc** que viene junto con las librerías *default* de python.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Mediante el uso de la función **collect()** de la librería de **gc**, puedes invocar al administrador de memoria de Python para eliminar objetos o variable que ya no tiene ninguna referencia de Código próxima.

Por ultimo si necesitas conocer el uso de tu memoria en un Código de Python o simplemente para verificar el funcionamiento del Código anterior, puedes usar la librería **psutil** con la función **psutil.virtual_memory()**, de la siguiente manera:

```
import psutil
psutil.virtual_memory()
```

Resultado:

```
svmem(total=25712619520, available=16066732032, percent=37.5, used=9645887488, free=16066732032)
```

Para darle manejo a lo que se imprime en pantalla, puedes hacer uso **IPython.display** que cuenta con muchas funciones para darle manejo a la información en la consola, en este caso importados el módulo **clear_output** para limpiar la salida en consola.

Ejemplo:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
clear_output()
```

también puedes usar el comando **%reset** para eliminar todas las variables del espacio de trabajo

```
%reset
```

Por último para eliminar las figuras abiertas, puede usar la función de **matplotlib** con el atributo especificado, en este caso **all**

Ejemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
```